# How can I keep UI elements responsive while my program is working?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-ndk

The UI I am creating includes a button, which once pressed, is supposed to find and display values repetitively until the user presses the button again.

This is my button's initialization with the listener:

```
pollOn = false;
pollButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.pollButton );
    pollButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i( "POLL BUTTON", "onClick" );
            if( !pollOn ) {
                Log.i( "POLL BUTTON", "!pollOn" );
                pollOn = true;
                methodToReadAndDisplayData();
            } else {
                Log.i( "POLL BUTTON", "else pollOn" );
                pollOn = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

It is not shown here to make things easier to read, but the way I currently have it working is to call the `methodToReadAndDisplayData()` 5 times in a for loop and then stop.

So when I press the `pollButton` initially, the UI freezes and `Log.i("POLL BUTTON", "onClick")` is displayed at the top of `LogCat`. I then press the `pollButton` while it appears to be frozen, and after all of the work is done and the UI unfreezes, `Log.i("POLL BUTTON", "onClick")` is shown at the very end of my `LogCat`. The way I am interpretting this is that the button click is entered into a queue, and the `onClick` method is called after all 5 iterations of the for loop have been completed.

Another large part of this problem is that the work being done is mainly in a native library, and is called using the NDK. I am unsure if this has anything to do with the UI freezing, but it definitely increases the processing time needed.

If anything is unclear or confusing please let me know and I will try to clarify things.

Any information on this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some stuff while keeping the UI responsive can achieved by many methods, two of them are very common. Async Task and threads.

**AsyncTask:**

It's a class which have a few methods which help you to do time consuming work while updating the UI at the same time. For Example: If you want to search a specific word in a big document, do the reading and searching stuff in `doInBackground()` (a method of AsyncTask class) and you can display a progress bar and notify the user with your progress with `onProgressUpdate()`. This gives your app more professional feel and at the same time helps you executing time consuming task in background.

**Threads:**

They are simple runnable threads. You can execute non UI stuff with these threads but you can't perform UI tasks in them (as UI is not thread safe). For dealing with UI in these threads, you will have to use `Handlers`, which is quite cumbersome for beginners to get a grip and understanding of them.

So depending on your needs and app you can choose the one best suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're running on the main thread the system UI freezes, you'd be better off running in a new thread which would leave your UI running as normal. Below is an example of how to run your method in a new thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        methodToReadAndDisplayData();
    }
}).start();
```

Note that if your method interacts with the UI in any way, you need to do it via the following:

When you want to update your UI:

```
Handler threadHandler = new Handler();
threadHandler.post(updateRunnable);
```

Update your UI here:

```
Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        example.setText(newValue);
    }
};
```

Try that and see if there's any improvement. I've not worked with the NDK, just the standard SDK so there may be difference I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Do it on another thread. Use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to call methodToReadAndDisplayData.